# Cannot send Broadcast with PERMISSION to a receiver of another application in android

Tags: android, permissions, broadcast

I have 2 apps: app1, app2
I want to send a broadcast with a permission from app2 to a app1.

In AndroidManifest.xml app2:

```
<permission
    android:name="app2_sendbroadcast_permission"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>
```

Send a broadcast intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("app2_sendbroadcast_signal");
sendBroadcast(intent, "app2_sendbroadcast_permission");
```

In AndroidManifest.xml app1:

```
<uses-permission android:name="app2_sendbroadcast_permission" />

<receiver
      android:name="com.example.app1.App1Receiver"
      android:exported="true" >
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="app2_sendbroadcast_signal" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And the receiver of App1 to listen signal from App2:

```
public class App1Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // String str = intent.
        Toast.makeText(context, "Caught signal from sendBroadCast from App2",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

However, when I send broadcast from App2, there is nothing would happen. That means I cannot send a broadcast with a defined permission.

**Update:** 
My 2 apps: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5gseeqgdbz4k0u/Android%20Permission%20Test.zip

Please check and find my issue. Your comments are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the source code you shared, Permission name declared in App2 manifest is not matching with uses-permission string in App1 manifest.
2. Also, while sending broadcast from App2, permission string (2nd param) should be "app1_sendbroadcast_permission"
3. Intent's action should be "app1_sendbroadcast_signal" as App1Receiver is listening to "app1_sendbroadcast_signal" this action.

If this does not solve the issue, you can try below:

1. Check if broadcast is received properly without sending second parameter (permission string).
2. Its always good practice to define action String as com.test.example.APP1_SECURE_BROADCAST. Althugh, this String will not cause any issue.
3. While declaring permission, Try changing protection level to dangerous.
4. Check if you are getting any SecurityException.

**Correct Fix for this source code:**

Please follow proper guideline for defining permission string. Change permission String to something like "com.example.app2.SECURE"
Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html
It says:

*android:name
The name of the permission. This is the name that will be used in code to refer to the permission — for example, in a  element and the permission attributes of application components.
The name must be unique, so it should use Java-style scoping — for example, "com.example.project.PERMITTED_ACTION".*

Comment: I have consulted your guide but I am still getting the issue when putting a permission with Intent. Although, I can the receiver can receive successfully if there's no permission String.
I have just update the source code as your suggestion. Can you check again? I am still stuck

Comment: Permission which you have used is not as per Android guideline. Changing permission to string like "com.example.app2.SECURE" will solve the problem. Refer android:name section in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Comment: I don't know why I must name permission as above. However, now I can do it successfully. Thank you.